# Infinite coin toss model: How does the union of collection of subsets of $\left\{0,1\right\}^\infty$ is an algebra but not a sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand the application of measure extension in the context of probability theory (infinite coin toss model).

It is said in the lecture that,

$\Omega = \left\{ 0,1 \right\}^\infty$ 
$\mathcal{F_n} = $ Collection of subsets of $\Omega$ (whose occurance can be decided by looking at the first $n$ tosses)
$A \in \mathcal{F_n}$ if $\exists$ $A^{(n)}$ $\subseteq$ $\left\{0,1\right\}^n$ such that $A = \left\{ \omega \in \Omega \ | \ (\omega_1, \omega_2, ..., \omega_n) \in A^{(n)}  \right\}$
$\mathcal{F_0} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}^\infty \mathcal{F_n}$

> 1. $\mathcal{F_n}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra
> 2. $\mathcal{F_0}$ is an algebra but not a $\sigma$-algebra. (Is not a $\sigma$-algebra because it doesn't have events like "all heads" (or) "all tails")

Here's what I've tried,

1. To prove $\mathcal{F_n}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,
   (i) $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F_n}$,
   (ii) Any (countable) union or interesection of $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}^n$ for any $n$ is $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}$ and 
    $\left\{ 0,1 \right\} \in \mathcal{F_n}$,
   (iii) For any $A \in \mathcal{F_n}, A^c = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F_n}$,
   (iv) The whole set $\Omega$ is equal to $\left\{0,1\right\}$ since $\Omega \subseteq \left\{0,1\right\}$ and $\left\{0,1\right\} \subseteq \Omega$ and $\left\{0,1\right\} \in \mathcal{F_n}$.
   Hence proved.

I'm stuck with proving $\mathcal{F_0}$.
(Don't know how to start it since $\mathcal{F_0}$ seem like more of a union rather a collection of sets.)
It would be great if someone could review my work above and help to prove the $\mathcal{F_0}$.

Please refer [this lecture](https://youtu.be/EUyHG83NXeU?list=PLbMVogVj5nJQqGHrpAloTec_lOKsG-foc&t=1448) by Dr. Krishna Jagannathan to get more context.

Thank you!

Comment: Just glancing at this, I think you are confusing sets and sets of sets.

Comment: @Trebor I see. Can you point where you sense it because I'm still doubting the correctness of the proof for $\mathcal{F_n}$

Comment: In general, if $\{\mathcal{F}_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a monotone nondecreasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras, $\mathcal{G}:=\bigcup_n\mathcal{F}_n$ is an algebra, but may not be an $\sigma$-algebra. Proving that $\mathcal{G}$ is an algebra is easy, as in your proof. The issue is that if $\{A_m:m\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset\mathcal{G}$, then $\bigcup_mA_m$ is not in $\mathcal{G}$ necessarily.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Since, $\mathcal{F_0} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F_n}$ is a countable union, how to prove that $\bigcup_m A_m$ is not in $\mathcal{F_0}$?

Comment: @DeepakS.M. You may cook-up a counter example with the toss coin paradigm (there are many others, of course) Consider the idealized game of tossing a fair coin infinitely many times. Let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be the $\sigma$ field generated by the first $n$-tosses. The event where only hades comes up in even tosses is not in $\mathcal{G}=\bigcup_n\mathcal{F}_n$. The algebra $\mathcal{G}$ is in a sense a little myope, it does not give to much information about the future.